# gnuplot installation error undefined reference

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to install gnuplot4.6.tar.gz on a fedora2 machine. I am doing the following:
tar -xvzf gnuplot4.6.tar.gz
cd gnuplot 4.6.0
./configure
make
make install

However, running 'make' gives the following error:
./term/gd.trm:717: undefined reference to `gdFontGetTiny'
term.o(.text+0x200a7):../term/gd.trm:724: undefined reference to`gdFontGetSmall '
term.o(.text+0x200ae):../term/gd.trm:731: undefined reference to `gdFontGetMediu mBold'
term.o(.text+0x200b5):../term/gd.trm:738: undefined reference to`gdFontGetLarge '
term.o(.text+0x200bc):../term/gd.trm:745: undefined reference to `gdFontGetGiant '
term.o(.text+0x21fca): In function`PNG_set_font':
../term/gd.trm:1840: undefined reference to `gdFontGetTiny'
term.o(.text+0x21fd9):../term/gd.trm:1838: undefined reference to`gdFontGetGian t'
term.o(.text+0x21fe0):../term/gd.trm:1836: undefined reference to `gdFontGetLarg e'
term.o(.text+0x21fe7):../term/gd.trm:1834: undefined reference to`gdFontGetMedi umBold'
term.o(.text+0x21fee):../term/gd.trm:1832: undefined reference to `gdFontGetSmal l'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [gnuplot] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/sayantika/gnuplot/gnuplot-4.6.0/src'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sayantika/gnuplot/gnuplot-4.6.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/sayantika/gnuplot/gnuplot-4.6.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Currently, the machine has gnuplot 3.7
Has it anything to do with the architecture of the machine?

cat /proc/cpuinfo gives the following output:
cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 15
model           : 2
model name      : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 2.00GHz
stepping        : 7
cpu MHz         : 1999.412
cache size      : 128 KB
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 2
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe cid
bogomips        : 3956.73

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it looks like you may have an outdated version of a library gnuplot depends on.  What version of libgd do you have installed?

Comment: Yes, the problem here is definitely libgd.  If you don't care about those terminals, you can build without it.  (`gd` supplies the `gif`, `png` and `jpg` terminals), but there's also a `pngcairo` terminal which is (in my opinion) superior to the `png` terminal which makes having the gd terminals enabled slightly less important...

Answer (score 0):

I commented the  following lines in src/term.h. This solved the problem and gnuplot 4.6 got installed.

```
 #if defined(HAVE_GD_PNG) || defined(HAVE_GD_JPEG) || defined(HAVE_GD_GIF)
 #include "gd.trm"
 #endif
```